# dividing outputs in make by filename

Tags: bash, makefile

I am processing some files and want to at one point create two categories depending on the filename so I can compare the two. Is this possible in a makefile?

```
%.output1: %.input
    ifneq (,$(findstring filename1,$(echo $<)))
        mv $<.output1 $@
    endif

%.output2: %.input
    ifneq (,$(findstring filename2,$(echo $<)))
        mv $<.output2 $@
    endif

%.output_final: %.output1 %.output2
    do_something
```

I think there is two things wrong with this code:

1. There is a mistake in the ifneq line.
2. %.output1 %.output2 will always use the same filename - it may not be possible to do this in 'make' and this may require ruffus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tab-indented the `ifneq` line so make doesn't consider it a make directive and is considering it a shell command and attempting to pass it to the shell to execute (hence the shell error you removed in your recent edit).

Use spaces (or no indentation) on that line to have make process it correctly. That being said having done that you cannot use `$<` in the comparison as it will not be set at that point.

`$(echo)` is also not a make function. You have mixed/confused processing times. You cannot combine make and shell operations that way. (Not that you need `echo` there to begin with.)

If you want the comparison to happen at shell time then do not use make constructs and instead use shell constructs:

```
%.output1: %.input
    if [ filename1 = '$<' ]; then
        mv $<.output1 $@
    fi
```

Though that is also incorrect as `$<` is `%.input` and `$@` is `%.output1` for whatever stem matched the `%`. That rule should probably look more like this (though I'm having trouble understanding what you are even trying to have this rule do so I may have gotten this wrong).

```
%.output1: %.input
    # If the stem that matched the '%' is equal to 'filename1'
    if [ filename1 = '$*' ]; then
        # Then copy the prerequisite/input file to the output file name.
        cp $< $@
    fi
```

I'm not sure I understand your second question point. The `%` in a single rule will always match the same thing but between rules it can differ.

This `%.output_final: %.output1 %.output2` target will map the target file `foo.output_final` to the prerequisite files `foo.output1` and `foo.output2`. But will also map any other `*.output_final` file to appropriately matching prerequisite files.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. You have answered the second question: the idea was for last rule to accept any output from output1 and any output from output2 and then compare the two going through the different permutations. That is not possible using this format and easier to do in another language.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? How are you expecting to find "any" `*.output1` and any `*.output2` files? What is generating them? Is make not doing that? If you just want to take the first file to match those two globs and compare them you can do that with make (though that seems an odd task to begin with and a slightly odder one to use make for).